# WPF - Change style programmatically, "can't find style"

Tags: wpf, styles

Exception Message:

System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException: ''{StaticResource style1}' resource not found.'

C# code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button newBtn = new Button();

  newBtn.Height = 30;

  //newBtn.Style = Resources["style1"] as Style;
  newBtn.Style = (Style)FindResource("{StaticResource style1}");

  stackpanel1.Children.Add(newBtn);
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<Grid.Resources>

  <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">


    .....styleofbutton
  </Style>

</Grid.Resources>



<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource style1}" Margin="128,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" Height="61" Click="Button_Click"/>
<StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="292" Margin="348,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395"/>
```

newBtn can't find my style in the XAML code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Style should be visible to the Button,in this case the Button and the Style should be in the Same Grid, or move the Style to window.Ressources or to the app.Xaml file.

Answer (score 1):

The key of the resource is simply "style1":

```
newBtn.Style = (Style)FindResource("style1");
```

You should also either move `Style` to `<Window.Resources>` or look for it in the `Grid`:

```
newBtn.Style = theNameOfTheGrid.Resources["style1"] as Style;
```

Comment: The global resource dictionary's "keys" are the strings that you set in the style. 
<Style x:Key="MyKey" />

So when programmatically trying to find that style by name, as MM8 said, all you need to do is pass the name. Typically I prefer using "TryFindResource" so it doesn't throw an exception, but if all of your resources are local to the view then the FindResource works fine.