# Breadcrumbar ItemTemplate won't changed when customized?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I want to change the BreadcrumberItem style(Template) in Breadcrumber.I had changed the itemTemplate of BreadCrumber. But it always takes the default style of BreadcrumberItem.
My Complete Project [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1isVJyJJ7zLk4tj32Fzi8ZkojYMGrfwZl?usp=sharing) . I want to change the next indication ChevronIcon(PART_ChevronTextBlock) text to "/" .

My xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <controls:BreadcrumbBar x:Name="bread" Width="200" Height="100">
        <controls:BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:BreadcrumbBarItem">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_LayoutRoot">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Flyout x:Name="PART_EllipsisFlyout">
                            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisFlyoutPresenterBackground}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisFlyoutPresenterBorderBrush}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisFlyoutPresenterBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
                                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}">
                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="FlyoutPresenterScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"/>
                                                    <Border x:Name="FlyoutPresenterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.CornerRadius>
                        <ThemeResource ResourceKey="ControlCornerRadius"/>
                    </Grid.CornerRadius>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="PART_ContentColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="PART_ChevronColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ItemTypeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Inline"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="EllipsisDropDown">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ContentColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.Padding" Value="11,7,11,9"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.Margin" Value="5,3"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="True"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EllipsisDropDownItemCommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InlineItemTypeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Default">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="/"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultRTL">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="/"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LastItem">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_LastItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_LastItemContentPresenter.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="True"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Ellipsis">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="/"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_EllipsisTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="EllipsisRTL">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_EllipsisTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="/"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Button x:Name="PART_ItemButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="0" FocusVisualMargin="-3" IsTabStop="False" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarItemButton" Padding="1,3" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarNormalForegroundBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarItemThemeFontSize}"/>
                                <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarNormalForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="CurrentNormal">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentNormalForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarHoverForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="CurrentPointerOver">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentHoverForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarPressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="CurrentPressed">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentPressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="CurrentDisabled">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focus">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarFocusForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="CurrentFocus">
                                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentFocusForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" AutomationProperties.Name="ContentPresenter" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                        <Grid AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarItemGrid">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ItemContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" LineHeight="20" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarItemContentPresenter" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_EllipsisTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarEllipsisTextBlock" Padding="3" Text="&#xE712;" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_LastItemContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Foreground="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentNormalForegroundBrush}" FocusVisualMargin="-3" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" LineHeight="20" Padding="1,3" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PART_ChevronTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarNormalForegroundBrush}" FontFamily="SegoeUI" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" AutomationProperties.Name="ChevronTextBlock" Padding="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronPadding}" Text="/" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </controls:BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:BreadcrumbBar>
</Grid>
```

In c#:

```
 bread.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "g", "j", "o", "p" };
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want to do.

1. Bring the `DefaultBreadcrumbBarItemStyle` from **generic.xaml**.
2. Remove the `DefaultBreadcrumbBarItemStyle` key.
3. Change all `{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}` to `{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}`.
4. Override `<x:String x:Key="BreadcrumbBarChevronLeftToRight">&#xE974;</x:String>` to `<x:String x:Key="BreadcrumbBarChevronLeftToRight">/</x:String>`.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CustomBreadcrumbBarItemStyle" TargetType="BreadcrumbBarItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarItemThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarItemFontWeight}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="BreadcrumbBarItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_LayoutRoot" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ItemTypeStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Inline" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="EllipsisDropDown">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ContentColumn.Width" Value="*" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.Padding" Value="11,7,11,9" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.Margin" Value="5,3" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="False" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_LayoutRoot.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="True" />

                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EllipsisDropDownItemCommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisDropDownItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InlineItemTypeStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Default">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronLeftToRight}" />

                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DefaultRTL">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronRightToLeft}" />

                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="LastItem">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_LastItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ItemButton.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="False" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_LastItemContentPresenter.(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)" Value="True" />

                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Ellipsis">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronLeftToRight}" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_EllipsisTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="EllipsisRTL">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="PART_EllipsisTextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ItemContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="PART_ChevronTextBlock.Text" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronRightToLeft}" />

                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Flyout x:Name="PART_EllipsisFlyout">
                                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisFlyoutPresenterBackground}" />
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisFlyoutPresenterBorderBrush}" />
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarEllipsisFlyoutPresenterBorderThemeThickness}" />
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2" />
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
                                            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}" />
                                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40" />
                                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource OverlayCornerRadius}" />
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" BackgroundSizing="InnerBorderEdge">
                                                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="FlyoutPresenterScrollViewer" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                                            <Border x:Name="FlyoutPresenterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" />
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                </Flyout>
                            </Grid.Resources>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="PART_ContentColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="PART_ChevronColumn" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button x:Name="PART_ItemButton" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" Grid.Column="0" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarItemButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" IsTabStop="False" FocusVisualMargin="-3" Padding="1,3" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarNormalForegroundBrush}" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}" />
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarItemThemeFontSize}" />
                                        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarNormalForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <!-- Current refers to the last item -->
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="CurrentNormal">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentNormalForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarHoverForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="CurrentPointerOver">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentHoverForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarPressedForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBackgroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarBorderBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="CurrentPressed">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentPressedForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarDisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="CurrentDisabled">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentDisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Focus">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarFocusForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="CurrentFocus">
                                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                        <Setter Target="PART_ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentFocusForegroundBrush}" />
                                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.Name="ContentPresenter" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                                <!-- This is the Button Content -->
                                <Grid AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarItemGrid" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ItemContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarItemContentPresenter" Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" LineHeight="20" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PART_EllipsisTextBlock" AutomationProperties.Name="BreadcrumbBarEllipsisTextBlock" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Padding="3" Text="&#xE712;" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Button>
                            <!-- ContentPresenter to be shown only when the rendered item is the Current Item -->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_LastItemContentPresenter" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" FocusVisualMargin="-3" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarCurrentNormalForegroundBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" LineHeight="20" Padding="1,3" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            <!-- ContentPresenter to be shown only when the rendered item is a drop down Item -->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_EllipsisDropDownItemContentPresenter" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            <!-- TextBlock that contains the chevron icon -->
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_ChevronTextBlock" AutomationProperties.Name="ChevronTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronFontSize}" Foreground="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarNormalForegroundBrush}" Text="&#xE76C;" Padding="{ThemeResource BreadcrumbBarChevronPadding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />

                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <BreadcrumbBar ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
        <BreadcrumbBar.Resources>
            <x:String x:Key="BreadcrumbBarChevronLeftToRight">/</x:String>
            <Style
                BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomBreadcrumbBarItemStyle}"
                TargetType="BreadcrumbBarItem" />
        </BreadcrumbBar.Resources>
    </BreadcrumbBar>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It works and it will override the Generic.xaml file for overall app. but I want to change the style for specific breadcrumbBar using key?

Comment: Yes. You just need to assign a key to the style.

Comment: we can't add breadcrumbBarItem in Breadcrumber.Because,the breadcrumb bar does not have an Items property, it only has an ItemsSource property. This means we can't populate the breadcrumbs in XAML or by adding them directly to an Items collection in code. Then how to change the Style using key?

Comment: I updated my answer. See that I also moved the ``BreadcrumbBarChevronLeftToRight`` to the ``BreadcrumbBar.Resources``.

Comment: how to handle if BreadcrumbBar object in c# not in xaml?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121654/wpf-change-style-programmatically-cant-find-style) might help.